# NativeScript : An Uncaught Exception Occurred on main thread on android(In ios runs perfectly)

Tags: nativescript

**I am new to nativescript i developed a simple app for learning purpose. i tried to run it in ios it works.whereas in android i cant run
the following is the error iam facing**
[image]

Following is my Package.json

```
{
  "description": "NativeScript Application",
  "license": "SEE LICENSE IN <your-license-filename>",
  "readme": "NativeScript Application",
  "repository": "<fill-your-repository-here>",
  "nativescript": {
    "id": "org.nativescript.excercises",
    "tns-ios": {
      "version": "2.5.2"
    },
    "tns-android": {
      "version": "2.5.0"
    }
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "nativescript-checkbox": "^1.2.6",
    "nativescript-platform-css": "^1.4.0",
    "nativescript-star-ratings": "^0.1.0",
    "nativescript-theme-core": "~1.0.2",
    "nativescript-web-image-cache": "^3.4.0",
    "tns-core-modules": "^2.5.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-traverse": "6.23.1",
    "babel-types": "6.23.0",
    "babylon": "6.16.1",
    "lazy": "1.0.11",
    "nativescript-dev-android-snapshot": "^0.*.*"
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is this a Xiaomi (Redmi) device you are running on? They are known to be distributed with an android platform SDK that is not quite the same as the standard one. https://github.com/NativeScript/android-runtime/issues/404

Comment: yes it is a redmi tab.so what should i do to make it work.is the link u mentioned got any solution?

Comment: No, the issue still hasn't been resolved I am afraid.

Comment: Anyway thankyou for your try @pkanev